# how to get buddy press messages based on thready_id?

Tags: php, buddypress

I tried a lot but could not get out of this, i am using standard loop which they provide but still it only shows all threads instead of all messages .While, I want to have messages for each thread so that I can show that for each client at their own screen. Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php 
                      //Getting user id from query string 
                      $chat_id = $_GET['user_id'];
                      if ( bp_has_message_threads( 'user_id='.$chat_id.'&box=sentbox;&box=inbox;&amp;max=10&amp;amp;per_page=10' ) ) { ?>        
                        <div class="large-center full-height-cnt">
                            <div class="body-continer">
                              <div class="head-option">
                                  <h2>Conversations between You and <span class="green-text"><?php echo bp_core_get_user_displayname( $chat_id ); ?></span> (Coach)</h2>
                              </div>
                              <div class="message-box">
                                <?php while ( bp_message_threads() ) { bp_message_thread(); ?>
                                  <div class="section-cnt">
                                    <div class="single-sectn">
                                      <div class="avatar-large">
                                            <img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/55197e87008006dcc554261d15335890?s=50&amp;r=g&amp;d=mm" class="avatar user-8-avatar avatar-50 photo" width="50" height="50" alt="Profile photo of akram">
                                      </div>
                                        <!-- avatar-large -->
                                            <div class="comment-box">
                                              <h3 class="name-cl"><?php echo bp_core_get_user_displayname( $chat_id ); ?><!--joe Smith-->
                                                <span class="f-right">
                                                  1 hour ago <span class="piper"> | </span> <a href="<?php bp_message_thread_delete_link(); ?>"> <i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                </span>
                                              </h3>
                                              <span class="subject">
                                                Subject: <?php bp_message_thread_subject(); ?>
                                              </span>
                                              <p>
                                                <?php bp_message_thread_content(); ?>
                                              </p>
                                              <div class="replay-button">
                                                <a href="javascript:;">Reply</a>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                            <!-- single-sectn -->
                                            <div class="replay-box">
                                                <h3 class="name-cl">You
                                                  <span class="f-right">
                                                    1 hour ago <span class="piper"> | </span> <a href="javascript:;"> <i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                  </span>
                                                </h3>
                                                <span class="subject">
                                                  Subject: Changes  Requried
                                                </span>
                                                <p>
                                                  I need to change the Program "Running in Summer"
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                              <!-- /.replay-box -->
                                  </div>
                                  <?php } //while?>
                                  <!-- /.section-cnt -->

                                  <div class="section-cnt">
                                    <div class="single-sectn">
                                      <div class="avatar-large">
                                            <img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/55197e87008006dcc554261d15335890?s=50&amp;r=g&amp;d=mm" class="avatar user-8-avatar avatar-50 photo" width="50" height="50" alt="Profile photo of akram">
                                      </div>
                                        <!-- avatar-large -->
                                            <div class="comment-box">
                                              <h3 class="name-cl">joe Smith
                                                <span class="f-right">
                                                  1 hour ago <span class="piper"> | </span> <a href="javascript:;"> <i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                </span>
                                              </h3>
                                              <span class="subject">
                                                Subject: Changes done !
                                              </span>
                                              <p>
                                                  Hi, i have made changes in your planner 2016<br>
                                                  Please check the programe "Running in summer" <br>
                                                  sesstion...
                                              </p>
                                              <div class="replay-button">
                                                <a href="javascript:;">Reply</a>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                            <!-- single-sectn -->
                                            <div class="replay-box">
                                                <h3 class="name-cl">You
                                                  <span class="f-right">
                                                    1 hour ago <span class="piper"> | </span> <a href="javascript:;"> <i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                  </span>
                                                </h3>
                                                <span class="subject">
                                                  Subject: Changes  Requried
                                                </span>
                                                <p>
                                                  I need to change the Program "Running in Summer"
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                              <!-- /.replay-box -->


                                  </div>

                              </div>
                              <!-- /.message-box -->
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <?php } else { //.if  ?>
                        <?php //else { ?>
                        <div class="large-center full-height-cnt">
                            <div class="body-continer">
                              <div class="head-option">
                                  <h2>Conversations between You and <span class="green-text"><?php echo bp_core_get_user_displayname( $chat_id ); ?></span> (Coach)</h2>
                              </div>
                              <div class="message-box">
                              Sorry, No Messages Found ... !
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php  } ?>
```

It shows only one message while I want all messages or I can say whole chat between those two users. Any body to help me out please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dig a little deeper into the [BP Messages file](https://svn.buddypress.org/branches/2.0/bp-messages/bp-messages-template.php) and you will see that `bp_message_thread_content()` only outputs the last message in the thread.
Similarly with `bp_message_thread_subject()`. `bp_message_thread()` sets up the last message data but no other message data.

Instead it looks like you want a new class of `BP_Messages_Thread_Template` to output the messages for the thread. eg.

```
 while ( bp_message_threads() ) {
      bp_message_thread();
      $thread_id = bp_get_message_thread_id();
      $order = 'DESC'; // or 'ASC'
      new BP_Messages_Thread_Template( $thread_id, $order );

      // so that instead of `bp_message_thread_content()
      while ( bp_thread_messages() ) {
          bp_thread_the_message();
          bp_the_thread_message_content();
      }

  }
```

There are more methods/functions for that class but that should get you in the right direction... :-)

Comment: thank you very much it helps like a charm, but I just want one more question now please ... kindly help me how to start first conversation ... what ever thread id returned, I'll be using that thread id for ever between those 2 members ... how to get this thing plz ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, you want only the first thread instead of looping? if so, instead of `while` you could use `if (bp_has_message_threads()) {bp_message_thread();` ...? if not you may need to clarify further.